# Error Installing apk in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

**Tools:**

- Android Studio 2.3
- Firebase

**Device Tested**

- Samsung GT-I9505
- Samsung SM-T211

**Device OS:**

- Android 5.0

**Problem:**
I can't install my app on my android device. Been troubleshooting what goes wrong.

**Display Error Message:**

```
Installation failed with message device 'a408a2f4' not found.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling 
an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

**Displayed Event Log:**

```
11:38 AM    An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
                    java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
                    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
                    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
                    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
                    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:492)
                    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.uploadApk(SplitApkInstaller.java:152)
                    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:78)
                    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:904)
                    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask$SplitApkInstaller.installApp(SplitApkDeployTask.java:117)
                    at com.android.tools.idea.run.RetryingInstaller.install(RetryingInstaller.java:86)
                    at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask.perform(Spl... (show balloon)

11:38 AM    Session 'app': Error Installing APKs
```

**Weird Event seen**

- I haven't had installed my app in my device yet it is displaying that i should uninstall my app.
- I've seen that when installing APK to my physical device goes offline and goes back to online. I don't know what is causing this behavior.

**What I've done so far**

- Checked my device settings in the developer options to allow usb debugging
- Checked my Sha-1 my package name it is being correctly registered to Firebase Console
- Checked in my Device Application Manager if my app is being installed but i can't see it
- Restarted my PC maybe it is experiencing cache issues on ADB. I had deleted it in task manager but not resolving.

Hoping for your utmost consideration. Thank You.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried installing it on different devices? It seems there's just an error with the connection between your machine and the device, basing from the logs.

Comment: It would appear that there is a physical error on the port or the cable. But it's just another possibility

Comment: If you run Eclipse and Android Studio together sometimes we face this `connection forcibly closed` exception. Or it could even with multiple instances of Android Studio.

Comment: In which device are you testing ? Instead of trigger _Uninstall_ option in device for application use _Uninstall for all user_. Also disconnect your USB first and again connect your device. If it won't work then restart your AS by `Invalid Cache and Restart`.

Comment: @AL  i had tried 2 Samsung devices

Comment: @Piyush just edited my post about the device i used

Comment: @Chisko i won't disregard that possibility but had tested 2 cables already

Comment: have you tried `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server`?

Comment: @falsify did u fixed the issue ????? I also have the same problem. If u fixed pls help.

Comment: I got similar issue when trying to install my app on Android 5, then i tried to do with Android 6 device and it worked fine. Still don't know the cause yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had same problem today after update to android studio 2.3

i just downgrade build:gradle version from `2.3.0` to `2.2.3` and solve my problem

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' // downgrade to this version
    }
}
```

Comment: today after updating entire `sdk` i tried again with `2.3.0` and it's worked

Comment: Thank you so much, god bless you !)
gradle 2.3.0-beta1 seems has a bug

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me:

I had same problem earlier. After long research it fixed by a small thing.I just uninstalled the driver of mobile in PC and changed the port to connect with that device. I think some problem with the port in my PC.It might be helpful to you.

Comment: Used samsung kies app for drivers to be read from my computer

Comment: can you try to just change the hardware port that your device is connected ?

Comment: I had changed usb ports 2.0 and 3.0 and status still the same

Comment: have you tried to connecting a device without kies app , means installing      goggle's usb driver.