# Error while Installing APK in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, apk

I can't install my app on my Android device.

After updating Android Studio to 2.3, I'm getting an error while installing the APK. My app has crashed leaving an error message that it has unfortunately stopped.

> minSdkVersion 14
>
> targetSdkVersion 24
>
> versionCode 1
>
> versionName "1.0"

Comment: did you get a log trace?

Comment: nope its working fine when i run directly,but error message when i install apk .

Comment: what is the android version of the device? and what logcat msg do you get?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after updating AS to `2.3.0`.

The solution is to downgrade `build:gradle` version from `2.3.0` to `2.2.3`.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42594373/7361696

Comment: You should provide the solution in your answer, not only a link.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I'll pay attention.

the solution is to downgrade build:gradle version from 2.3.0 to 2.2.3